# Why does git-svn make branches with names like trunk@34663

Tags: git, git-svn

I am writing a SVN to Git migration script. When I run `git svn clone` git-svn creates a handful of remote branches that ends in `@svnrevision` (for example `trunk@34663`).

Why are these branches created and what are they used for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That points to latest revision of a branch that was deleted. `trunk@34663` means trunk as it looked before it was deleted in revision 34664. It may have been created again in later revision, but since the state that was deleted does not have to be part of the ancestry of the new state, the deleted state is kept in this way.